# Area of uniform convergence of Stirling's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, number-theory, uniform-convergence, gamma-function

For $s \notin (-\infty, 0]$, Stirling's formula is:
$$
\log \Gamma(s) = \left(s - \frac12 \right) \log s - \frac12 \log 2\pi - \int_0^\infty \frac{P_1(x)}{s + x} dx
$$
where $P_1 (x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor - 1/2$ is the sawtooth function. In Davenport's *Multiplicative Number Theory*, it says that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{P_1(x)}{s + x} dx = O(\vert s \vert^{-1})
$$
as $\vert s \vert \to \infty$ on $-\pi + \delta < \arg s < \pi - \delta$ for each $\delta > 0$. However, I am wondering if it holds on whole $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$; here is my attempt for proof.

Write $s = \sigma + it$ with $\sigma, t \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $P_2(x) = (x^2 - x)/2$ for $x \in [0, 1]$ and $P_2(x) = P_2(x+1)$ for all $x$. Then $P_2' = P_1$ so by integration by parts,
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{P_1(x)}{s + x} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{P_2(x)}{(s+x)^2} dx.
$$
Also $P_2$ is bounded by some $M > 0$,
$$
\left\vert \int_0^\infty \frac{P_2(x)}{(s+x)^2}dx \right\vert \le \int_0^\infty \frac{Mdx}{\vert s+ x \vert^2} = M \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x+\sigma)^2 + t^2}.
$$
By symmetry, let us consider $t \ge 0$. Then
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x+\sigma)^2 + t^2} = \frac{1}{t} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1} \frac{\sigma}{t}\right) = \frac{\tan^{-1} (t/\sigma)}{t}.
$$
where the value $\tan^{-1} (t/\sigma) / t$ is interpreted as $\pi / 2t$ for $\sigma = 0$ and $1/\sigma$ for $t = 0$.

Write $s = R e^{i\theta}$ with $0 \le \theta < \pi$. Let us consider the three cases: $0 \le \theta < \pi / 2$, $\theta = \pi/2$, and $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$. For $0 \le \theta < \pi / 2$,
$$
\frac{\tan^{-1} (t/\sigma)}{t} = \frac{\theta}{R \sin \theta} \le \frac{\pi/2}{R}.
$$
For $\theta = \pi / 2$, $\tan^{-1} (t/\sigma) / t = \pi / 2R$. For $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$,
$$
\left\vert\frac{\tan^{-1} (t/\sigma)}{t}\right\vert = \frac{\pi - \theta}{R \sin \theta} \le \frac{\pi/2}{R}.
$$
Thus $\tan^{-1} (t/\sigma) / t = O(R^{-1})$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$. Is there anything wrong in my proof?

Comment: $\frac\pi2-\arctan(y)=\arctan(1/y)$ only works for $y>0$.

Comment: You can easily show that the result cannot be uniform on the plane minus the negative half plane by looking at the behavior of $\Gamma$ near the negative integers as exponentiating the result  above easily gives a contradiction

Comment: @TravorLZH Thanks, I found out my error and could write down right proof.

Comment: For the largest region of validity (in the sense of Poincaré), see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/1968409).